# How to make async data work with dynamic form pattern in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm using the dynamic form pattern in Angular with various form that we have. This is a convenient way for us as we only need to define our controls in `ngOnInit` and it will dynamically build the form that we need. However, there are some forms that values must be initialized and some of the values can be retrieve using async/await.

This is a problem with the dynamic form as when I'm initializing async data it throws errors on the console and the form is not showing up on the view.

I have tried to add async on the ngOnInit and await for the async data. As the sample code shows below:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    const pageUrl = await this.fooService.getTabUrl();
    const security = this.barService.getSecurity();

    const controls: Array<ControlBase<any>> = [
        new ControlTextbox({
            key: "url",
            order: 0,
            readonly: true,
            type: "text",
            value: pageUrl
        }),
        new ControlDropdown({
            key: "security",
            label: "Security",
            order: 2,
            options: security,
            type: "dropdown",
            value: security[0].id
        })
    ];
    this.controls = controls;
}
```

I also add an async pipe on the view:

```
<form class="{{formClass}}" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form" role="form">
    <app-form-control *ngFor="let ctrl of controls | async" [control]="ctrl  | async" [form]="form | async"></app-form-control>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" [disabled]="!form.valid">{{btnText}}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

However, this is not working.

For more details please see the screenshot.
[image]

Additional codes:

```
export class FormControlComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public control: ControlBase<string | boolean | undefined>;
    @Input() public form: FormGroup;

    constructor() { }

    get valid() {
        return this.form.controls[this.control.key].valid;
    }

    get invalid() {
        return !this.form.controls[this.control.key].valid && this.form.controls[this.control.key].touched;
    }

    ngOnInit() { }
}

export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public controls: Array<ControlBase<any>> = [];
    @Input() public btnText = "Submit";
    @Output() public formSubmit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    public form: FormGroup;

    constructor(public _controlService: FormControlService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        const sortedControls = this.controls.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
        this.form = this._controlService.toControlGroup(sortedControls);
    }

    onSubmit(): void {
        this.formSubmit.emit(this.form.value);
    }
}

export class FormControlService {
    constructor() { }

    public toControlGroup(controls: Array<ControlBase<any>>) {
        const group: any = {};

        controls.forEach(control => {
            const validators: any = [];

            // Required
            if (control.required) {
                validators.push(Validators.required);
            }

            // remove for brevity

            group[control.key] = new FormControl(control.value || "", validators);
        });

        return new FormGroup(group);
    }
}
```

I'm still new and learning the Angular. Any suggestion on how I will overcome the issue when initializing async data?

Comment: What does your `FormControlService.toControlGroup()` return? Looks like your form needs to be a `FormGroup` but is something else. I usually get this error when I add `[formGroup]="form"` to my form, where `form` is not set to the proper value/type. Also make sure the controls you are looping over also have a proper `[formGroup]` set, since they need one as well and this error can be thrown for those too.

Comment: @Lansana I have updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I typically will ad an `ngIf` statement on the form element if it is waiting on any Async data, or if the form is particularly complex. Basically what is happening, and I think you already know this, is that the form isn't initializing in time to beat the page being rendered to the screen. Depending on the circumstances, it may throw the error sometimes and it may not. By adding:

```
<form *ngIf="form">
```

You'll force angular to wait until `form` has been instantiated. The other issue I see could be due to the fact that you are pre-populating your formcontrols during the form instantiation process using async data. This typically doesn't bode very well. A better way (unless you have the data handy immediately), is to instantiate an emtpy form, followed by a call to get the data you want to put in the form. Then, use the `get()` and `setValue()` methods to populate the form controls. To the user, the difference isn't even noticeable, but this is a much more reliable method of pre-populating forms in my opinion. For example this is what you could do to prepopulate the "User Role Name" of a user role edit form:

**some-component.component.ts**

```js
ngOnInit() {
    // Instantiate your form.
    buildUserRoleFormGroup();
}

buildUserRoleFormGroup() {

    // INSTANTIATE YOUR FORM HERE.....

    // Then populate it.
    populateUserRoleForm();
}

populateUserRoleForm() {
    this._UserRolesService.getUserRole(this.userRoleID)
        .subscribe(_UserRole => {
            // Save the data to a component property
            this.userRole = _UserRole.data;

            // Get the user role name form control
            let userRoleName = this.createUserRoleForm.get('userRoleName')
            // Set the user role name form control value
            userRoleName.setValue(this.userRole.userRoleName);
            },
            _Error => {
                console.log(_Error);
            })
    }
```

Comment: silly me I have forgotten using the *ngIf. I was able to make it work but not using the *ngIf to check the form instead I used it to check the controls. I would need to do some reading and practice on your last suggestion but if you could share a sample code for an insight?

Comment: I just updated my answer to include some example code on getting and setting form controls. Hope it helps.